# HTTP 400 Bad Request IIS Manager

Tags: http, iis, http-error, iis-manager

I hosted a website on IIS server and it was done successfully. I am able to access the website from outside of the server and it works fine **BUT** when I try to run the website from my IIS server by clickin on Browse link on IIS I get the login page but once I login I get 400 BAD REQUEST error.

[Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NyCM.png)

Can anyone guide me how to fix this issue on IIS so that I am able to run the website from my IIS server also.

Would appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Comment: Very likely to be a bug of IIS Manager that it generates an invalid URL for the browser. You might check what are the URLs your site bindings support, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: The most common cause of the Bad Request error 400 is an invalid URL, but it may occur due to a different cause as well. first please make sure that the URL you have entered is correct, if that doesn't work, you can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.